# What is difference between Windows 8 Mobiles app and Windows 8 metro style app

Tags: windows-8, windows-mobile, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I am newbie to windows platform.
I have few questions mentioned below.

1. What's diff between Windows 8 metro style app and the Windows 8 mobile app?
2. What diff languages I can use to develop windows mobile app?

The answers to above questions will quickstart my windows mobile development.

Waiting for your responses.

Comment: You have 6 questions there - its would be best to post each one separately.  FYI some of those questions are either duplicates or subjective and so are likely to be closed.

Comment: Just to clarify: WHen you say "Windows 8 Mobile" do you mean "Windows Phone 8", "Windows Mobile" (which doesn't have a v.8), or "Windows 8 Embedded" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. They are basically the same except for some API that are available for phone only
   Windows Phone 8 now shares a common core with Windows 8. This means you can expect to write apps for one and easily port it to the other, with UI retooling of course. Developers targeting both should use C#/VB + XAML  and JS for apps, and C++/D3D for games.
2. VB/C# + XAML, C++ + DirectX (for complex graphics), JS can be used Windows 8 surface but not with phone (got this from jump start to windows 8)